# Adding value to already declared MongoDB object with mongoose Schema

Tags: node.js, json, mongodb, mongoose, database-design

I am new to MongoDB and mongoose. I am trying to create a Node & MongoDB auction app. So since it is actually an online auction, users should be able to bid for items. I successfully completed the user registration, sign in page and authentication process, however, I am a bit stuck in the bidding page.

I created a Schema using mongoose and each item for auction is saved in the database. I want to add name and price of each user who bid for the item in the same object in MongoDB, like this:

```
{
    name: "valuable vase from 1700s",
    owner: "John Doe",
    itemId: 100029,
    bids: {
        100032: 30000,
        100084: 34000
    }
}
```

So each user will have ids like `100032: 30000`, and when they bid, their "account id: price" will be added under `bids` in the database object of the item.

I made some research and found some ways to solve the problem but I want to know if what I want to do is possible and if it is the right solution to do.

Thanks for giving me your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are indeed couple of ways to achieve what you want.

In my opinion, a collection called ItemBids, where each document includes this data structure, will benefit you the most.

```
{
   itemId: ObjectId # reference to the item document
   accountId: ObjectId # reference to the account
   bid: Number # the bid value
}
```

This pattern is suitable for your case because you can easily query the bids by whatever you want -
You can get all the account bids, you can get all the item bids, and you can sort them with native Mongo by the bid price.

Every time there's a bid, you insert a new document to this collection.

Another option is embedding an array of Bids objects in the item Object.
Each Bid object should include:

```
bids: [{
   account: ObjectId("") # This is the account
   price: Number
}]
```

The cons here are that querying it and accessing it will require more complex queries.

You can read more about the considerations
here:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/data-model-design
https://coderwall.com/p/px3c7g/mongodb-schema-design-embedded-vs-references

Answer (score 0):

The way you decided to implement your functionality is a little bit complicated.

It is not impossible to do that but, the better way is to use array of objects instead of a single object like this:

```js
{
  name: '',
  ..
  ..
  bids: [{
    user: 100032,
    price: 30000
  }, {
    user: 100084,
    price: 34000
  }]
}
```